# How do I allocate a std::string on the stack using glibc's string implementation?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stdstring, stack-memory

```
int main(void)
{
   std::string foo("foo");
}
```

My understanding is that the above code uses the default allocator to call new. So even though the std::string foo is allocated on the stack the internal buffer inside of foo is allocated on the heap.

How can I create a string that is allocated entirely on the stack?

Comment: Let me amend that to "how can I create a std::basic_string that is allocated entirely on the stack?"

Comment: Just to link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wanted to do just this myself recently and found the following code illuminating:

[Chronium's stack_container.h](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/containers/stack_container.h?view=markup)

It defines a new `std::allocator` which can provide stack-based allocation for the initial allocation of storage for STL containers.  I wound up finding a different way to solve my particular problem, so I didn't actually use the code myself, but perhaps it will be useful to you.  Do be sure to read the comments in the code regarding usage and caveats.

To those who have questioned the utility and sanity of doing this, consider:

- Oftentimes you know a priori that your string has a reasonable maximum size.  For example, if the string is going to store a decimal-formatted 32-bit integer,you know that you do not need more than 11 characters to do so.  There is no need for a string that can dynamically grow to unlimited size in that case.
- Allocating from the stack is faster in many cases than allocating from the heap.
- If the string is created and destroyed frequently (suppose it is a local variable in a commonly used utility function), allocating from the stack instead of the heap will avoid fragmentation-inducing churn in the heap allocator.  For applications that use a lot of memory, this could be a game changer.

Some people have commented that a string that uses stack-based allocation will not be a `std::string` as if this somehow diminishes its utility.  True, you can't use the two interchangeably, so you won't be able to pass your `stackstring` to functions expecting a `std::string`.  But (if you do it right), you will be able to use all the same member functions on your `stackstring` that you use now on `std::string`, like `find_first_of()`, `append()`, etc.  `begin()` and `end()` will still work fine, so you'll be able to use many of the STL algorithms.  Sure, it won't be `std::string` in the strictest sense, but it will still be a "string" in the practical sense, and it will still be quite useful.

Comment: You can use many of the STL algorithms on a bare array of char on the stack, but someone suggested that and got voted down. Questioner will have to decide which features of std::string he needs...

Comment: This doesn't work for glibc's std::basic_string, it calls the Allocator's default constructor, which StackAllocator doesn't support.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that `std::basic_string` has a template parameter for the allocator. But `std::string` is not a template and has no parameters.

So, you could in principle use an instantiation of `std::basic_string` with an allocator that uses memory on the stack, but it wouldn't be a `std::string`. In particular, you wouldn't get runtime polymorphism, and you couldn't pass the resulting objects into functions expecting a `std::string`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work?  Exactly how do you propose to have the allocator modify the stack frame of its caller?  Simply doing an alloca() in the allocator will not work because that memory would be automatically freed when the allocator returns the pointer, or when the std::string's constructor returns if the allocator was inlined.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the allocator could only work because he didn't say *where* on the stack data he wanted the string to be. The allocator would need access to a block of stack via instance data. A bit like DJB's safe string libraries (C, not C++), which use a limited block of stack space because it's a cheap and easy way to limit memory use per thread

Comment: "*where* on the stack data he wanted the string to be". I mean, "where on the stack he wanted the string data to be". And I may have misremembered DJB's code, it was a while ago I saw it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Except...

`std::string` is an instantiation of

```
std::basic_string<class CharType, 
                  class Traits=char_traits<CharType>, 
                  class Allocator=allocator<CharType> >
```

You could conceivably define an Allocator class that uses [alloca](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Variable-Size-Automatic.html#Variable-Size-Automatic) for memory management. This would only work if the Allocator itself, and the `basic_string` methods that invoke it directly or indirectly, are all `inline`. A `basic_string` object created with this allocator would not **be** a `std::string`, but it would behave (mostly) like it. However, this would be a fair amount of work for limited gains. Specifically, using this class to return values from a function would be a career-limiting move.

I have no idea **why** you or anyone else would want to do this.

Comment: +1, modulo the comment to my answer, that alloca doesn't really do it because std::basic_string calls down into the allocator, so it's "too late" by then to use alloca. Can't remember how alloca interacts with inlining though - maybe with brutal amounts it could just so happen to work for a particular STL implementation and compiler settings?

Comment: The compiler would need to go way out of its way to give inlined methods their own stack frame. OTOH, placing bets on that is *another* career-limiting move.

Comment: alloca isn't POSIX, so I'm not even going to consider it. As for why someone would want to do this,  I point you to Eric Melski's answer.

Comment: A use of this technique is to preserve data locality.This might be usefull when designing an AST, it is quite conceivable to decide the maximum size of a string identifier in an AST. There are probably dozens of other use cases. C++ is a perfectly suitable language to use for creating resource constrained designs.

Comment: This answer is wrong, `alloca` allocates from a functions local stack frame. Once this goes out of scope, the allocated memory is automatically released.

Comment: As discussed in the comments above, it's likely to work provided that there are no non-inline methods between the caller and the allocator. (I've edited the answer to emphasize this restriction.) But even if it did work, it's still a poor idea to implement this in practice. I wrote this as a thought experiment, not as a serious suggestion for someone to implement. Walking through how this _might_ work can shed some light on how `basic_string` and allocators work, and why you _can't_ do a lot with dynamic memory on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that doing such a thing would be difficult to do, I wonder why you want to do it? To allocate something entirely on the stack, the compiler needs to know at compile time what the exact size of the thing is - in your example it would need to know not only the size of the `std::string` metadata, but also the size of the string data itself. This isn't too flexible, you would probably need different string types depending on the size of the string data you are wanting to include in it - not that it would be impossible to do, just it would tend to complicate things up a bit.

Comment: "you would probably need different string types depending on the size of the string data you are wanting to include in it". Welcome to Symbian!

Answer (score -3):

- std::string will always manage it's internal storage with new/delete.
- Not sure why your question contains *glibc’s string implementation*. The string implementation of the c++ standard library has nothing to do with *glibc*.
- The only way to store a string on the stack is to use a C char array on the stack (like what Shhnap outlined). But that's probably not what you want anyway :-)

Comment: Is there really something in the standard regarding the first point.. AFAIK, the internal implementation is free to do small string size optimisations and not involve heap.

Comment: Majkara is correct, small strings(<16 chars in the MSVC implementation) are usually allocated on the stack and don't involve any heap memory allocation.

Comment: std::string defines the interface not the implementation. I'm specifically asking about the glibc implementation because it's what I'm working with. If I was using the MSVC implementation I wouldn't be asking this question. Fortunately I've been provided with an answer that is implementation independent.

Comment: @poindexter glibc does NOT have a std::string implementation. it's in libstdc++ from gcc.

Comment: @Majkara Tito The fact that the implementation of some compilers do small string size optimisations does not mean that you can write (portable) C++ where your string is not hep allocated.