# std::string with no free store memory allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stdstring

I have a question very similar to

[How do I allocate a std::string on the stack using glibc's string implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783944/how-do-i-allocate-a-stdstring-on-the-stack-using-glibcs-string-implementation)

but I think it's worth asking again.

I want an `std::string` with local storage that overflows into the free store. `std::basic_string` provides an allocator as a template parameter, so it seems like the thing to do is to write an allocator with local storage and use it to parameterize the `basic_string`, like so:

```
std::basic_string<
char, 
std::char_traits<char>, 
inline_allocator<char, 10> 
> 
x("test");
```

I tried to write the `inline_allocator` class that would work the way you'd expect: it reserves 10 bytes for storage, and if the `basic_string` needs more than 10 bytes, then it calls `::operator new()`. I couldn't get it to work. In the course of executing the above line of code, my GCC 4.5 standard string library calls the copy constructor for `inline_allocator` 4 times. It's not clear to me that there's a sensible way to write the copy constructor for `inline_allocator`.

In the other StackOverflow thread, Eric Melski provided this link to a class in Chromium:

http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/base/stack_container.h

which is interesting, but it's not a drop-in replacement for `std::string`, because it wraps the `std::basic_string` in a container so that you have to call an overloaded `operator->()` to get at the `std::basic_string`.

I can't find any other solutions to this problem. Could it be that there is no good solution? And if that's true, then are the `std::basic_string` and `std::allocator` concepts badly flawed? I mean, it seems like this should be a very basic and simple use case for `std::basic_string` and `std::allocator`. I suppose the `std::allocator` concept is designed primarily for pools, but I think it ought to cover this as well.

It seems like the rvalue-reference move semantics in C++0x might make it possible to write `inline_allocator`, if the string library is re-written so that `basic_string` uses the move constructor of its allocator instead of the copy constructor. Does anyone know what the prospect is for that outcome?

My application needs to construct a million tiny ASCII strings per second, so I ended up writing my own fixed-length string class based on `Boost.Array`, which works fine, but this is still bothering me.

Comment: As someone who's wrestled with custom allocators in the past, I'm very interested in hearing an authority speak on this topic.

Comment: +1 for "free store". Oh, and because it's a good question.

Comment: The link to [Generic: A Policy-Based basic_string Implementation](http://drdobbs.com/184403784) is terrific discussion of basic_string storage. 

I still wonder, though, if it is possible to write the `inline_allocator` class in my question. A brief glance at Alexandresu's article doesn't tell me the answer, I'll have to spend some time with it.

Comment: The link to Chromium's stack_container.h is dead. Here's an updated one: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/containers/stack_container.h?view=markup

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Andrei Alexandrescu, C++ programmer extraordinaire who wrote "Modern C++ Design" once wrote a great article about building different string implementations with customizable storage systems.  His article ([linked here](http://drdobbs.com/184403784)) describes how you can do what you've described above as a special case of a much more general system that can handle all sorts of clever memory allocation requirements.  This doesn't talk so much about `std::string` and focuses more on a completely customized string class, but you might want to look into it as there are some real gems in the implementation.

Comment: That's a great article by Alexandrescu, thanks. This is a very good answer to the question of how to customize storage for basic_string.

Answer (score 10):

C++2011 is really going to help you here :)

The fact is that the `allocator` concept in C++03 was crippled. One of the requirement was that an allocator of type `A` should be able to deallocate memory from any other allocator from type `A`... Unfortunately this requirement is also at odds with stateful allocators each hooked to its own pool.

Howard Hinnant (who manages the STL subgroup of the C++ commitee and is implementing a new STL from scratch for C++0x) has explored [stack-based allocators on his website](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html), which you could get inspiration from.

Comment: That's very interesting. I looked at Hinnant's `stack_alloc` class and it works splendidly for `std::vector` but alas, not for `std::basic_string`. The problem is again, I believe, in the way `std::basic_string` uses the `stack_alloc` copy constructor.

Comment: And I think it is permitted to use the copy constructor that way because of the requirement you described.

Comment: @James: yes, unfortunately since the standard all but imply that the allocators are stateless (or at the very least that all allocators of the same type more or less share the same state, somehow), copies are perfectly allowed.

Answer (score 6):

This is generally unnecessary. It's called the "short string optimization", and most implementations of `std::string` already include it. It may be hard to find, but it's usually there anyway.

Just for example, here's the relevant piece of `sso_string_base.h` that's part of MinGW:

```
  enum { _S_local_capacity = 15 };

  union
  {
_CharT           _M_local_data[_S_local_capacity + 1];
size_type        _M_allocated_capacity;
  };
```

The `_M_local_data` member is the relevant one -- space for it to store (up to) 15 characters (plus a NUL terminator) without allocating any space on the heap.

If memory serves, the Dinkumware library included with VC++ allocates space for 20 characters, though it's been a while since I looked, so I can't swear to that (and tracking down much of anything in their headers tends to be a pain, so I prefer to avoid looking if I can).

In any case, I'd give good odds that you've been engaged in that all-too-popular pass-time known as premature optimization.

Comment: VC++ allocates 16 bytes for the SSO, which in my opinion is too small to be generally useful as `std::wstring` is more commonly used in Windows code than `std::string` and that only allows for 8 characters in a `std::wstring` (or 7 if `.c_str()` is used frequently).

Comment: Doesn't the header belong to MinGW library extensions (not part of std::string)?

Comment: @UncleBens: I didn't think so, but I could be mistaken. There are also alternatives (e.g., STLPort, libc++) that definitely do use SSO in their implementations of `std::string`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Looking again, you're quite right, and I agree that is a bit on the small size. I still think it would be easier to modify it and re-compile the standard library than try to hack it on afterwards though.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the term "short string optimization." I need to be able to control the threshold length of the short string optimization. And I'm not kidding about the million strings constructions per second.

Comment: @James Brock: Surely -- and I never doubted it. As for controlling the threshold, in most cases it's a matter of finding the `enum` in the header, modifying it as needed, and (possibly) re-compiling the standard library to match (but since it's a template, there's a good chance you only need to modify the header).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin : Speaking for VC++, pre-VC++ 2010, `std::basic_string<char>` and `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` are pre-instantiated and exported from the CRT rather than being header-only, making changing the size of the SSO quite painful. For VC++ 2010, `std::basic_string<>` is now purely header-only, making it trivial, as you say.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the code from Chromium just wraps things into a nice shell. But you can get the same effect without using the Chromium wrapper container.

Because the allocator object gets copied so often, it needs to hold a reference or pointer to the memory. So what you'd need to do is create the storage buffer, create the allocator object, then call the std::string constructor with the allocator.

It will be a lot wordier than using the wrapper class but should get the same effect.

[You can see an example of the verbose method (still using the chromium stuff) in my question about stack vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage).