# Where is the memory for a local C++ vector allocated?

Tags: c++, vector

I noticed that the memory for vector is allocated dynamically. So for a local vector, where does the memory is allocated?

```
f(){

 vector<int> vi;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? Are you talking heap vs. stack?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The vector is allocated on the stack (28 bytes on my system). The vector contents are allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 5):

You can change how memory is allocated for STL containers with the combination of Allocator template type and the allocator object passed to the constructor.

I asked a question about how to make a vector use stack storage and got [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage) You might find it interesting.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Yacoby's answer, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) means that when `vi` goes out of scope, anything allocated with `new` (inside the vector) is `delete`d (in the vector's destructor). That's how you mix stack and heap allocation.

Answer (score 3):

The `vector` is allocated wherever the `allocator` it uses decides to allocate from.

In the default case of `std::allocator`, it uses `::operator new()`.