# String class allocating on stack for small strings?

Tags: c++, string, stl, memory-management, wstring

Do anyone know if there is a STL interface compatible string class that allocates memory for small strings on the stack (up to a certain threshold) and the heap for larger strings ?

I'm looking to optimize a program and I'm using allot of small local strings that easily could fit on the stack, instead of being allocated on the heap.

Comment: Visual Studio has this optimization (for very small string, just a couple characters) while gcc preferred the Copy-On-Write.

Comment: We use Visual Studio 2010 , is there anywhere you can read about this optimization (MSDN or elsewhere) ?

Comment: Most compilers will do that, if you have a recent enough version.

Comment: Looked it up and it appears to be 16 bytes in VS 2010 , no option to set it to anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a custom allocator for `std::basic_string` (it is the third template argument). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage/354481#354481) explains how use that and links to an implementation of a stack-allocator that can be used.

Comment: Some implementation of std::string do this, it's called the small string optimisation. A quick google should tell you if yours does or if there is an alternative you can use.

Answer (score 2):

This is antique question, but I feel that this is better that any of the current answers.

http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#dss_smallstring

Basically it is what you want. 
BTW tcmalloc increased perf in my (badly designed :D) string alloc intensive program 10%. 
Also you should profile to prove allocs are your perf problem.

Answer (score 1):

The vstring (__versa_string) implementation from gcc can do the small string optimization and has a std string interface. If you happen to be using gcc it's easy enough to include ext/vstring. Otherwise you may be able to adapt it to your compiler/enviroent.

Answer (score 0):

__versa_string SSO version can store no more than 15 bytes on the stack and if it does, it reserves 16 bytes regardless of the string size ( http://codepad.org/2M7N9cTu ).

http://www.and.org/ustr/ can reuse a stack buffer, but I had problems linking with it under Debian Wheezy 64bit.

http://freecode.com/projects/str-class can reuse a stack buffer.

I wrote a header-only string class which uses just four bytes and can reuse a stack buffer:
http://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/gstring.hpp 
It has a limited STL compatibility: basic_streambuf implemented for use with std::ostream.