# handling arrays in class declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I just wrote a simplified implementation of the stack data structure in a class, but the handling of an integer array is behaving in a way that I can't seem to understand.

The same snippet of code as in `push()` will give the behavior I expect, but in this program assigning a value at a certain array position will assign the value to the index variable>

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class stack
{
public:
    stack(int size)
    {
        ar_size = size - 1;
        array[ar_size];
        index = 0;
    }
    void push(int value)
    {
        cout << "index; " << index << endl; //will output 0
        cout << "value: " << value << endl; //will output 8
        array[index++] = value;
        cout << "index; " << index << endl; //will output 8
        cout << "value: " << value << endl; //will output 8
        cout << "array: " << array[index] << endl; //will output what seems to be a memory address
    }
    int pop()
    {
        cout << "index; " << index << endl; //will output 8
        return array[index--];
    }
private:
    int ar_size;
    int array[];
    int index;
};
int main()
{
    stack tower(64);
    tower.push(8);
    int r = tower.pop();
    cout << "pop: " << r << endl; //will output what seemed to be a memory address

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this statement actually supposed to do: `array[ar_size];`? I have a feeling it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings + read and understand warnings = PROFIT !

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I see your point, I had got an error by declaring the array size in the private definition and ended up making this mistake. so, how and where should I try to declare the array size?

Comment: @maja Best is to use a `std::vector<int>`, and initialize it with `ar_size` in the constructor member initializer list: `std::vector<int> array;`  `stack(int size) : array(size) { // ...`

Comment: @Hiroaki I'm not sure what result I should expect, if I try this in the constructor the program chrashes, if I try it in the private section I get the same error as trying to set `array[]` with a size: invalid use of non-static data member stack::ar_size`.

Comment: @Paul thanks, I enabled them

Comment: @maja: great - did you *read* the warnings ?

Comment: @Paul yes, in this case it pointed out that `array[ar_size];` was not having any effect (and thus no error was raised). it looks like a very useful kind of warning.

Comment: @maja: good - you should always take notice of warnings - this can save you an awful lot of debugging time later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected code of your example:

```
#include <iostream>

class stack
{
public:
   stack(int size)
   {
      ar_size = size - 1;
      array = new int[size];
      index = 0;
   }
   void push(int value)
   {
      array[index++] = value;
   }
   int pop()
   {
      return array[--index];
   }
   ~stack()
   {
      delete array;
   }
private:
   int ar_size;
   int *array;
   int index;
};

int main()
{
   stack tower(64);
   tower.push(8);
   int r = tower.pop();
   std::cout << "pop: " << r << std::endl; //Will output 8 :)

   return 0;
}
```

There were several issues with it.

1. As pointed out in the comments `array[ar_size];` in your constructor did not do what you wanted it to. `array[ar_size];` accesses the array at the given index, it does not allocate the array for you. I've fixed the problem so that the array is now allocated via `new` and deleted when the stack is destroyed.
2. `return array[index--];` was not right as well. You need to lower the index before accessing the element. `return array[--index];` is now right.
3. You're missing a BUNCH of checks so that your stack does not cause a `segfault` or any other undefined behaviour. You need to check if you can still push values or if you can pop values and so on.

I hope it clears things up a bit.

Comment: the one thing I could not have spotted myself is the fact that I need to use the heap for handling an array between the function of a class, I'll change the title according to that..  (it's still too early to assess segfaults for me).

Comment: You are not required to use the heap. But you can not dynamically allocate memory on the stack in that way. If you wanted there are [some ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335023/c-how-to-allocate-memory-dynamically-on-stack) to do it but it's a lot easier this way.

Comment: I'll have to read for a while with that, but the heap seems good enough for now. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic memory allocation.Something like this

```
private:
int ar_size;
int *array;//pointer to array
int index;
```

and then in the constructor

```
stack(int size)
{
    ar_size = size - 1;
    array=new int[ar_size];
    index = 0;
}
```

Since this is dynamic memory allocation make sure to free the allocated memory.You can have a destructor

```
~stack()
{
  delete[] array;
}
```

Another point is after you push an element,you increase the `index` by `1`.So now index does point to the next insertion point in the stack.So if you do a pop operation it will remove an element from `index` location but there is no element there yet.So you can change your `pop` function to

```
int pop()
{
    cout << "index; " << index << endl; //will output 8
    return array[--index];//now index will point to the top element
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `delete` somewhere. This will cause a memory leak. A destructor which would clean up would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `array = new int[ar_size];` instead of `array[ar_size];`. You'll need to make a destructor that does `delete [] array;` as well then.