# Can I dynamically create instances of C++ objects in the stack?

Tags: c++

Just as it's possible to create a new instance of an object in the heap using `new Class()`, is it possible to create an object in the stack?

I'm learning about heap vs stack.

One way, in C++, is to have a static member in the cpp code:

```
static MyObject myObject;
```

but suppose that I have this:

```
static int emptyArray[100000];
```

there's sufficient RAM space, not allocated by the OS, for me to build my object. Can I use a custom allocator and build my object in a subset of this array? How would I do that?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/Ambeco/mpd/blob/master/SmallContainers/erasable.hpp

Comment: Have a look at the [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ How to allocate memory dynamically on stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335023/c-how-to-allocate-memory-dynamically-on-stack)

Comment: The object created by`static MyObject myObject;` is not on the stack. It's also not on the heap. There's another region of storage for objects with static storage duration.

Comment: As @super says, but be sure to note the use of `alignas`.

Comment: @MooingDuck can you explain to me what this code does?

Comment: tldr; `mpd::erasable<Shape, 100000> myObject = Square(10);`. It allows you to store values with derived types on the stack, using a fixed size buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just as it's possible to create a new instance of an object in the heap using `new Class()`, is it possible to create an object in the stack?

Sure, simply declare it, without `static`, as a local variable inside of a function, eg:

```cpp
void doSomething()
{
    ...
    MyObject myObject; // <-- allocated on the stack
    ...
}
```

> suppose that I have this:
>
> `static int emptyArray[100000];`
>
> there's sufficient RAM space, not allocated by the OS, for me to build my object. Can I use a custom allocator and build my object in a subset of this array?

You don't need a custom allocator, you can use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) for that, eg:

```cpp
static int emptyArray[100000];
...
MyObject *myObject = new (&emptyArray[offset]) MyObject; // <-- allocated inside of emptyArray
...
myObject->~MyObject(); // <-- must call destructor manually
```

Just make sure that `offset` is an even multiple of `MyObject`'s size and alignment.  You can use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) to help you with that, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

static const int MaxObjects = ...;
static std::aligned_storage<sizeof(MyObject), alignof(MyObject)>::type emptyArray[MaxObjects];
...
MyObject *myObject = new (&emptyArray[index]) MyObject;
...
myObject->~MyObject();
```

Comment: does this mean that I can use C++ to dynamically create objects in microcontrollers using `new` even though they have no OS to handle memory allocation? I can just pass an array of enough size?

Comment: @Paprika yes. When using `new`/`delete`, the compiler allocates/frees memory for objects. When using `placement-new`, you handle that yourself instead.