# Visual C++11 stack allocator for std::list and std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, allocator, visual-c++-2012

I'd like to increase the performance of a specific usage of list and map, where the number of items has a hard limit in the order of 100000. The STL default allocator obviously isn't the best choice in this situation, since cleaning up all the thousands of small objects takes a very long time (>10sec!). Not to mention all the other potential issues.

So obviously to improve this I can preallocate the correct amount of memory to contain all of the list/map nodes. So far I've been able to implement a working version of the default allocator (by deriving from std::allocator_traits), that uses alloc/free for each node. But I'm struggling to find out how to modify this to allow for the "stateful" use of, for example, my very simple stack:

```
using namespace std;
class MemPoolStack
{
public:
    size_t Size;
    size_t Mult;
    size_t Total;
    size_t Top;
    size_t Last;
    unique_ptr<byte[]> Data;
    unique_ptr<size_t[]> Nexts;

    MemPoolStack(size_t size, size_t mult) :
        Size(size),
        Mult(mult),
        Total(size * mult),
        Top(0),
        Last(0),
        Data(new byte[Total]),
        Nexts(new size_t[Size])
    {
    }
    size_t& Next(size_t i)
    {
        return *(Nexts.get() + i);
    }
    void* Pop()
    {
        byte* p = nullptr;
        if(Top<Size)
        {
            p = Data.get() + (Top * Mult);
            bool last = (Top==Last);
            size_t next = last ? Top+1 : Next(Top);
            if(last) Next(Top) = next;
            Top = next;
            if(Top>Last) Last=Top;
        }
        else
        {
            p = nullptr;
        }
        return p;
    }
    bool Push(void* p)
    {
        ptrdiff_t diff = (byte*)p - Data.get();
        size_t index = ((size_t)diff / Mult);
        if(diff>=0 && index<Size)
        {
            Next(index) = Top;
            Top = index;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

template <class T> struct MemPool
{
    typedef T value_type;
    MemPool() throw() {}
    template <class U> MemPool (const MemPool<U>&) throw() {}
    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef MemPool<U> other; }; //off-topic: why doesn't allocator_traits define this?
    T* allocate (size_t n) 
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(malloc(n*sizeof(T))); 
    }
    void deallocate (T* p, size_t n) 
    { 
        free(p); 
    }
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator== (const MemPool<T>&, const MemPool<U>&) throw()
{return true;}

template <class T, class U>
bool operator!= (const MemPool<T>&, const MemPool<U>&) throw()
{return false;}
```

And I'm instantiating my list and map like this:

```
list<TKey, MemPool<TKey>> Keys;
map<TKey, MapType, less<TKey>, MemPool<MapType>> Map;
```

The `MemPoolStack` itself isn't really the issue here, it probably has bugs but it's just for example purposes. The point is that the `MemPoolStack` class stores a `unique_ptr` to the preallocated memory, and some other member variables.

The problem there is that I need to have some reference to my `MemPoolStack` in the `MemPool` class, so that all the different ways that a Visual C++11 map or list can construct my allocator all end up with one `MemPoolStack` instance per list or map. Then I could use `MemPoolStack::Pop()` in `MemPool::allocate()`, and `MemPoolStack::Push()` in `MemPool::deallocate()`.

I also need a way to initially construct my allocator, specifying the size. I tried putting a `shared_ptr<MemPoolStack>` in `MemPool` but it ended up getting lost when the list decided to call the allocator's default constructor...

I'm also open to throwing away all of this code for a good alternative solution to the original problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for C++ STL-like vector class but using stack storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage)

Comment: You don't need the stack. If you are good with a single block of stack memory, then you are good with a single block of heap.

Comment: STL allocators are stateless. All instances of any given allocator type must be equivalent to all other instances of that type. Sorry, that's the law of the land.

Comment: If you want stateful allocators, try Boost collections, I hear they explicitly support them.

Comment: "Custom allocators may contain state. Each container or another allocator-aware object stores an instance of the supplied allocator and controls allocator replacement through std::allocator_traits.  (since C++11)" (from [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator))

Comment: I'm just not sure how to implement said state.

Comment: @n.m. - that was the law of the land **before** C++11.

Comment: you are probably using 
STL wrong if it takes 10s to deallocate thousands of objects, not to mention that probably u should not be using list.... paste a small example where you experience your perf problems...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I'm implementing an LRU cache which requires storing hundreds of thousands of POD's (which are actually stored in a vector), indexed by a small key (32 bytes). The map is used as the primary lookup while the list serves as the LRU list. I don't really want to implement my own map and list, so I need to adapt the STL ones via an allocator to be more efficient for my use case.

Comment: can you sort the vector in a sense is that it is not being updated while lookups are running, or no?

Comment: also check out boost circular buffer for LRU if that suits your needs

Comment: @PeteBecker I stand corrected.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Well, essentially this is a circular buffer (LRU cache with fixed size). I'd prefer not to be moving around my data all the time (i.e a pointer to an object in the cache should remain the same), so the data goes in a fixed-size vector. But I still need the map and linked list functionality to make the cache work. I'm also a bit of a purist at the moment and this project will not be using Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a single underlying pool, and allocators can be copied and re-bound, you can't store your state directly in the allocator.

What you *can* do is store a pointer (or a `shared_ptr`) to your state, such that copies of your allocator shallow-copy the pointer, referring to the same underlying pool.

Note that you either need to write a default constructor for your allocator, and have it create a new backing pool, or you need to create an allocator instance with a specific backing pool and pass it to the container constructor.

So this:

```
list<TKey, MemPool<TKey>> Keys;
```

will default construct an allocator (which will be something like `MemPool<list<TKey>::node>`), and that allocator instance will have to create its own backing state; while this:

```
list<TKey, MemPool<TKey>> MoreKeys(Keys);
```

will *copy* that original allocator instance via a `select_on_container_copy_construction() const` method you must provide (so you can make both containers, with their separate allocator instances, share the same pool); and finally this:

```
map<TKey, MapType, less<TKey>, MemPool<MapType>> Map(MemPool<MapType>(my_pool));
```

will use the specified backing pool.

Comment: This is essentially my line of thinking, that my `MemPool` needs a `shared_ptr<MemPoolStack>` that can be reused when the allocator is copied (but I'm not intending on sharing allocators between containers). I also need a constructor `MemPool(size_t count)` or similar which can do the initial allocation of the shared_ptr. But how do I handle the default constructor case of `MemPool()`? i.e. where do I get the shared_ptr from?

Comment: I did try exactly this already, passing the allocator instance into the list constructor, as in `list<TKey, MemPool<TKey>> Keys(MemPool<TKey>(100000))`, but for some reason during that construction, `MemPool()` is being called.

Comment: I also tried `list<TKey, MemPool<_List_node<TKey,void*>>> Keys(MemPool<_List_node<TKey,void*>>(100000))` to avoid the rebind, but it didn't help.

Comment: If you delete `MemPool::MemPool()`, where does it fail to compile? Or alternatively, have it call `abort` and examine your call stack in a debug build. You should be able to figure out why it's getting called.

Comment: Good call. I have managed to get rid of this default constructor now, I <sigh> found another piece of code of mine lurking that was somehow doing it. With the culprit removed, I've now got both the shared_ptr and my custom constructor working! I'll post the full code in another answer and mark yours as answer since using shared_ptr definitely is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've gotten this working, once my brain cells were fired into action thanks to Useless.

Here's the code of the allocator (I've omitted the `MemPoolStack` here since it hasn't changed and probably is broken anyway, that's my next task - but the issue here was to get a working stateful allocator):

```
template <class T> struct MemPool
{
    typedef T value_type;
    shared_ptr<MemPoolStack> Stack; //My allocator's state goes here!
    template <class U> MemPool (const MemPool<U>& p) throw()
    {
        if(p.Stack->Mult!=sizeof(U))
        {
            throw runtime_error("Can't rebind MemPool to another size object. Sorry.");
        }
        Stack = p.Stack; //interestingly, this constructor is used by std::map but not std::list
    }
    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef MemPool<U> other; }; //off-topic: maybe they fixed this one in VS2019?
    MemPool(size_t count) :
        Stack(new MemPoolStack(count, sizeof(T))) //I can allocate the memory here!
    {
    }
    T* allocate (size_t n) 
    {
        //Now I can return Stack->Pop() here instead of using malloc!
        if(n!=1) throw runtime_error("MemPool can only allocate one item at a time. Sorry.");
        return static_cast<T*>(Stack->Pop());
        //return static_cast<T*>(malloc(n*sizeof(T)));  
    }
    void deallocate (T* p, size_t n) 
    { 
        ///Can use Stack->Push() here instead of free!
        if(n!=1) throw runtime_error("MemPool can only deallocate one item at a time. Sorry.");
        Stack->Push(static_cast<void*>(p));
        //free(p);
    }
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator== (const MemPool<T>&, const MemPool<U>&) throw()
{return true;}

template <class T, class U>
bool operator!= (const MemPool<T>&, const MemPool<U>&) throw()
{return false;}
```

However, my instantiation of all this is now a little more long-winded:

```
typedef pair<size_t, typename list<TKey>::iterator> MapType;
typedef MemPool<_Tree_node<pair<TKey,MapType>,void*>> MapPoolType;
typedef MemPool<_List_node<TKey,void*>> ListPoolType;

list<TKey, ListPoolType> Keys(ListPoolType(capacity+10));
map<TKey, MapType, less<TKey>, MapPoolType> Map(MapPoolType(capacity+10));
//I use list/map capacity+10 because the containers like a few free nodes to themselves.
//Probably should investigate further as to what these numbers actually need to be.
```

Setting a breakpoint in `MemPool::allocate()` shows that the `Stack` member is now always populated.

Great, Hooray for C++11!