# Why is alloca returning the same address twice?

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation, alloca

I'm trying to implement my own math library, and I'm starting off with vectors. The idea is to give the class a pointer to an array of numbers, then copy the array and store it in the data address given by a private variable pointer. To begin with, I used `alloca` to try and free up some memory for the private variable

**vml.h**

```
namespace vml {
    // Vectors
    template <typename in_type, const int in_length>
    class vec {
    public:
        vec(in_type* in_data) {
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
            std::copy(in_data, in_data + in_length, data);
        }
        vec() {
            data = nullptr;
        }
        in_type& operator()(int index) const {
            _ASSERT(0 <= index && index < in_length);
            return data[index];
        }

    private:
        in_type* data = alloca(in_length * sizeof(in_type));
    };
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    int list[] = { 1,2,3 };
    int list2[] = {2,4,6 };

    vml::vec<int, 3> a(list);
    vml::vec<int, 3> b(list);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives no errors however, for some reason, `alloca` returns the same address twice when calling two instances. I searched this up everywhere and I couldn't find an explanation why. So I decided to allocate memory using an array. If you can answer this question that would be extremely helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: you did declare `operator()` as `const`

Comment: 1st) Using `alloca()` (in C++) is bad idea in general. 2nd) Using `alloca()` for member variables seems to me an especially bad idea. Considering, that `alloca()` was meant for temp. local storage in functions (in C)... (I recalled [alloca()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) just to be sure that I didn't miss or confuse something...)

Comment: You need not only memory, but you need to construct objects (ie call their constructor). C memory allocation functions don't do that

Comment: this looks very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029951/4117728

Comment: Can't reproduce (even with fixes to make the code compile) the behaviour you describe in the first case.   The error message is because it is not possible to return a non-`const` reference to a (non-mutable) member of a `const` object.  Change the return type of the `operator()` to `const in_type &`.   The assignment `data = nullptr` should also not compile in the second case, but you have not mentioned that.

Comment: @Peter That's weird, that's all the errors that I get.

Comment: As you are using a compile time constant for the data length just replace the manual memory management with `std::array` this will place the data on the stack as you require.

Comment: @RichardCritten Can I just use the normal arrays `in_type data[in_length]`? Do you know to solve the issue with the constant array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to be ***very*** careful with `alloca`. It allocates memory on the stack rather than the heap. That memory is freed as soon as the function which called `alloca` exits. In this case, it will be called in the constructor so when you call `operator()` that memory has already been freed and you are dealing with undefined behavior.

Unless you really need to avoid heap allocations and you know for sure that you wont overflow the stack and you understand all the limitations of using `alloca`, it's best to steer clear of it.

Comment: I want to allocate memory on the stack though because I dont need to add more data to the list

Comment: @JoshuaPasa you might want to check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354442/looking-for-c-stl-like-vector-class-but-using-stack-storage

Comment: I called `alloca` outside of the constructor so shouldn't it stay around until the class instance is out of the scope?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa - I'm not sure exactly where the allocation happens when you use that initialization syntax in a class. I believe it's part of the constructor call but you'd have to check with a language lawyer on that. In any case, `alloca` is actually part of the C runtime. It has no concept of classes.

Comment: @Ferruccio is there any way to use alloca such that it only gets freed when the class is out of the scope. A bit like how variables in a class get freed. That's why I wanted to use `in_type data[in_length]` but for some reason, it initializes as a constant even though i didn't add `const` to the prefix, however, it does solve the issue of the memory address

Comment: @JoshuaPasa - No, all `alloca` does is increase the size of the current stack frame to make room for whatever you want to store there. As soon as the function returns the entire stack frame disappears.

Comment: `vec(in_type* in_data, in_type*a=(in_type*)alloca(in_length * sizeof(in_type))):data(a){...}` would pull alloca out of the constructor and let it live longer, but that's still an incredibly bad idea, the size you want to allocate is constant and alloca is meant for non-constant sizes.

Comment: @Ferruccio How comes it works when initializing an array inside of the class such as `in_type data[in_length]`?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa - because in that case you are defining an array whose scope is the same as the class scope. In the alloca case you are defining a pointer whose scope is the same as the class scope, but you are initializing it to a chunk of memory which will go out of scope as soon the the constructor is done. The pointer is still in scope and will still point to that same memory, but that memory is no longer yours.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the basics, your stack is most likely only 1 MB, so after a few vectors and recursive calls you program will likely die.

To solve it if you want it on stack you could use `std::array` as `data`

Warning untested code ahead

```
template <typename in_type, const int in_length>
class vec {
public:
    vec(in_type* in_data) {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        std::copy(in_data, in_data + in_length, data);
    }
    vec() = default;
    in_type& operator()(int index) const {
        _ASSERT(0 <= index && index < in_length);
        return data[index];

    }

private:
  std::array<in_type, in_length> data;
};
```

Alternatively if you want to use all the nice things from `std::array`

```
template <typename in_type, const int in_length>
class vec : public std::array<in_type, in_length> {
public:
  using std::array::array; // use constructors, might need template param to compile
}
```

This also means that if you at some point just want to change to heap you just allocate your vec as every other class.

Another alternative is to use C++17 PMR, use an allocation on the stack as the storage and make `vec` PMR aware.

Comment: Isn't vector just a wrapper then?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa the idea is that you can expand on the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wrap `alloca` in a function and return its pointer outside, since the stack of wrapper function would be freed.

If you call it as member initializer, it is actually called from constructor, and may be freed when constructor returns and then re-used.

Comment: But I called alloca not in a function

Comment: @JoshuaPasa, it is effectively called auto-generated part of initialization list, which is a part of constructor